# the sum of three columns in a inner Join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to link two tables together so I can get the following data out of them. But all I get is all the totals added to the first person and nothing for and other people.
It should look like it does below

```
pid firstname nid  Total
18  Teresa     3  65846.50
18  Richard    1  3005.00 
18  Camdon     7  2000.00
```

The join works but the sum is not working correctly

```
SELECT
    notarys.pid,
    notarys.firstname,
    notarys.nid,
    SUM(
    signings.samount+
    signings.prtamount+
    signings.faxamount
    )AS Total
    FROM
        notarys
    INNER JOIN signings ON notarys.nid = signings.nid
    WHERE
        signings.pid = signings.pid
    AND signings.done = 1
    ORDER BY
    notarys.nid ASC
```

Comment: and which is your php code?, please update your post and add your php code, so we can help you deeper

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` something. It's not really clear what without a bit more information about your structure. Maybe `GROUP BY notarys.nid`.

Comment: I suggest you to update question adding tables samples

Comment: table structure and keys info plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` is needed.

```
SELECT
    notarys.pid,
    notarys.firstname,
    notarys.nid,
    SUM(
    signings.samount+
    signings.prtamount+
    signings.faxamount
    )AS Total
FROM
    notarys
INNER JOIN signings ON notarys.nid = signings.nid
WHERE
    signings.pid = signings.pid
AND signings.done = 1
GROUP BY notarys.nid, notarys.pid
ORDER BY notarys.nid ASC
```